# Docker compose disabling my login to Azure Linux VM

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, docker-network, azure-vm

I am trying to deploy the airflow docker compose to my azure linux vm.
when i run (apache airflow) docker compose on azure VM.

```
docker-compose up
```

It tries to create a network and kicks me out of SSH. Thereafter , I am not able to login to the VM.

Can someone plz help?

Comment: Have you more information regarding the 'It tries to create a network and kicks me out of SSH' messages you get?

Comment: No as soon as I run 'docker-compose up', first statement appears in the terminal   as 'creating default network airflow_scheduler_default ' and then nothing happens after that. After that I am not even able to login to VM to see what happened.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of all the outputs? Knowing you get an error when running `docker-compose up` is a bit too generic to be able to help debugging - Also, please share the docker-compose.yml so to have an idea of what you're trying to boot up

Comment: It's possible that Docker is selecting an address for the network created by docker-compose that somehow conflicts with your access to the vm...but there's not enough information here to make that determination.